# Incorrect default backend set for matplotlib after installing pyside

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyside

I installed Python version 3.4.2 using `pyenv` on Ubuntu 14.04, I then installed `pyside`:

```
$ pip install pyside
```

and then installed `numpy` and `matplotlib`:

```
$ pip install numpy
$ pip install matplotlib
```

If I now try to import `matplotlib` from `ipython`:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib
/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:1039: UserWarning: Bad val "pyside" on line #39
    "backend      : pyside
"
    in file "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc"
    Key backend: Unrecognized backend string "pyside": valid strings are ['emf', 'GTK', 'GTK3Agg', 'nbAgg', 'CocoaAgg', 'GTKAgg', 'pgf', 'agg', 'Qt4Agg', 'pdf', 'ps', 'cairo', 'MacOSX', 'WX', 'WebAgg', 'gdk', 'svg', 'TkAgg', 'GTK3Cairo', 'template', 'Qt5Agg', 'WXAgg', 'GTKCairo']
  (val, error_details, msg))
```

If I edit the `matplotlib` cofiguration file:
`/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc`: I can see that it has a line:

```
backend      : pyside
```

If I change this to:

```
backend      : Qt4Agg
backend.qt4 : PySide
```

It works fine..

The question is: Why does the `matplotlibrc` file have an invalid backend (`pyside`) value in the first place?

Comment: Must have something to do with packaging. On Windows here and Matplotlib 1.4.2 the default backend is Qt4Agg and the default backend.qt4 is PyQt.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why there is nonsense in the matplotlibrc in the matplotlib package you installed. You might want to ask that directly to the developers of [matplotlib](http://sourceforge.net/p/matplotlib/mailman/).

However one can override these settings programmatically and then should be independent of any such settings.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt4']='PySide'
```

Comment: Thanks @Trilarion. I already asked a question at the matplotlib mailing list: http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Incorrect-default-backend-set-for-matplotlib-after-installing-pyside-td44771.html

Answer (score 0):

`pyqt5` is default installation version in every `anaconda`, it would be better thus just use `matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')`

`import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')`